# Training from remote resources

Tags: tensorflow, keras

All,

I've researched this some and haven't found a clear answer anywhere.

Using Keras with TF backend, how can you train a model using assets (like images for example) that are not local, but remote assets.

For example, if you have 1M images on s3 that are labeled but not organized by folder, is there a practical way to stream in data in a way Keras can use to train a model?

My thinking is that I would supply a file that was of the format:

```
{ label: "Apple", img: http://someurl/img.jpg }
{ label: "Banana", img: http://someurl/img.jpg }
{ label: "Orange", img: http://someurl/img.jpg }
```

You could use `preprocessing.load_img` or `pillow` to grab and resize the url.

This question is more about the correct process for this and the feasibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be possible by mirroring Keras' generator API. You can make a standard python generator that has an index of image URLs, and yields batches of images loaded from those URLs.

However, I would not recommend this approach. Loading images from the web introduces extra latency, which has the potential to significantly slow down your model's training. The only case where it might be a good idea is if you literally do not have the space on your SSD to store the whole dataset, and/or you find that the time it takes to load a batch of images images is short compared to the time it takes to train on that batch.